# Enable Swagger UI for Specific user in spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using Swagger UI in Spring boot for interactive REST endpoints representation. However, Swagger UI can be accessed by everyone who knows its URL. Is there any standard way to restrict Swagger UI access with user login or key? I am also using JWT authorization for securing rest rest end points.I am using pringfox-swagger2 2.8.0.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/shop/charity/details/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/shop/all/details/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()

                .anyRequest().authenticated();

}
@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(customeUserDetailService);

    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("jwtToken", "Authorization", "header");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.test.controller"))     
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build().apiInfo(testAPI()).securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()));                                        
    }
    
    private ApiInfo testAPI() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("REST API")
                .description("\"Sixty REST API \"")
                .version("2.0.0")
                .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\"")
                .build();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic Authentication using Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110036/basic-authentication-using-swagger-ui)

Comment: @i.merkurev above mention is the not solution, I want to restrict the swagger-ui access to the user.

Comment: by setting a role to access the swagger using `hasRole("Some_role")` and then implement a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` to map claims to roles https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities-grantedauthoritiesmapper